# Vector class in a Flex Library Project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, vector, swc

i seem to be having some problems with the Vector class in actionscript 3

in a Flex Project or an ActionScript Project it is possible to do this

```
var v:Vector.<String>;
```

But when i do the same thing in a Flex Library Project (to create an SWC)
then i get the following error on that line of code
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: String.

so when using Flex Library Project it fails..., but when i compile the same thing using compc there are no problems

any idea why only the library project is complaining about Vector ?

btw this happens with all kinds off Vector declarations , not just String

```
var v:Vector.<String>
var v:Vector.<Number>
var v:Vector.<Object>
```

etc, all fail...

(i am using flex 4 sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need the latest Player Globals SWC: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html

Similar to [this](http://www.daveoncode.com/category/actionscript/) issue?

Comment: i have downloaded and addedd the new Globals SWC to the Library path of the Flex Library Project , but still the same.
i find i weird that it is complaining about not finding the String class... the Vector class seems to be ok.

does anybody else have the same problem btw ?
this can be tested by just creating a new Flex Library Project and creating a Vector variable of any kind.

Comment: i checked out the link you included, i could use -external-library-path with compc , but compc doesnt give me any errors.
and i think adding SWC to one of the paths in the Library Panel of the project is the same right ? or do i need to add it as a additional compiler argument ?

Answer (score 1):

add:

"-target-player 10,0,0"

under "Properties -> Flex Library Compiler -> Additional compiler arguments !

Then it works with Flex B. 3

Answer (score 0):

Check if your are publishing for a version flash >=10

Comment: yes i am for the Flex an ActionScript projects
but with a Flex Library project it is not possible to specify a flash version in the compiler settings

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems with Flex Builder 3 it is not possible to specify a minimim required flash player version for a Flex Library project , that's why it wasnt working.

i have tested the same thing in Flash Builder 4 , and now it is possible to specify that player version , which it possible to compile the Flex Library Project.

Thx for the answers Tegeril and Patrick you pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. I know with Flex Builder you can target a specific SDK, but yeah, not a player revision.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the "-target-player" compiler argument to "10,0,0".

Answer (score 0):

Adding  "-target-player 10,0,0" in Flex Builder 3 gives an error "configuration variable 'target-player' must only be set once".

To resolve it add the following line in Project -> Properties -> Flex Library Compiler -> Additional compiler arguments

```
-dump-config "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5(AIR 2.0)\frameworks\flex-config.xml" -target-player=10
```

this would dump the current configuration settings.